# How can I summarise these records in a single SQL query with no sub queries?

Tags: mysql

I have a basic SQL interface to create reports from a MySQL database consisting of responses to a form that I have created. The interface does not permit sub queries.

In the form there are five fields (field1 - field5) for which people can choose their preference in the form of "first choice", "second choice" etc.

My ideal output would summarise choices like this:

```
field1, first choice, 5
field1, second choice, 3
field1, third choice, 0
...
field5, fourth choice, 2
field5, fifth choice, 1
```

However any layout that summarises how many people chose which option for each field would work.

Is there a way to achieve this, or do I need five reports, one for each field (which would easy to do with five `SELECT field[n], count(*) FROM table WHERE 1 GROUP BY field[n]` style reports, replacing n with 1-5)

EDIT: Mockup table definition. This isn't the complete table and may not be 100% correct as I don't have access to the actual table. (For example, I guess that the field1-5 are actually `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` fields, but I don't know. `ENUM` illustrates the choices best though).

```
CREATE TABLE `Example` (
  `EntryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field1` enum('First Choice','Second Choice','Third Choice','Fourth Choice','Fifth Choice','Not Interested') NOT NULL,
  `field2` enum('First Choice','Second Choice','Third Choice','Fourth Choice','Fifth Choice','Not Interested') NOT NULL,
  `field3` enum('First Choice','Second Choice','Third Choice','Fourth Choice','Fifth Choice','Not Interested') NOT NULL,
  `field4` enum('First Choice','Second Choice','Third Choice','Fourth Choice','Fifth Choice','Not Interested') NOT NULL,
  `field5` enum('First Choice','Second Choice','Third Choice','Fourth Choice','Fifth Choice','Not Interested') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `Example`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`EntryID`);

ALTER TABLE `Example`
  MODIFY `EntryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Please post the exact definition for your MySQL table.

Comment: I don't have an exact definition because I didn't create the table, I only have an interface for entering SQL to run on the table. However I will make a fake table that would be about right and will update the post shortly with it.

Comment: You could easily combine the 5 queries into a single query using UNION.

Comment: I am not sure it's even possible to use UNION unfortunately. The interface I have looks like this: SELECT [I can enter SQL here] FROM Table WHERE [I can enter SQL here]

Comment: The problem is three fold. 1) the table schema is garbagy. What happens when a new `field` is needed? An Alter table? yuck. 2) your hands are tied in that you can only alter the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clause of a query making it so you can't `UNION` which is the only reasonable way to unpivot the bad schema. 3) I can't think of any nice way to get to your format given issues 1 and 2 (specifically 2). Perhaps if you generate a series (1-5) as a separate recordset, join to that to blow out your records, and then get creative with CASE you can get somewhat close. **Are you allowed to do joins?**

Comment: with that interface... you can only do it separately.

Comment: @JNevill - 1) The table schema isn't really relevant. If I add a new field to the form, the table schema is automatically updated by the system to have the new field available to me in the SQL. I have no control over this. I believe the table I am accessing is a temporary table created for the report. 2) Yes what I can do is very restricted, presumably to prevent me from doing bad things while still giving as much flexibility as possible for reporting. I have no ability to LEFT JOIN

Comment: It's relevant for the next visitor to this question stuck with the same issue that DOES have the ability to change their not-so-great-schema, but I agree it's not relevant to your situation since you have no ability to change any of that. Without a Join or Union I can't imagine a way to blow out 1 record into more than 1 record, and as such, I don't think there is anyway to do this (without extracting the data into another database and doing fancier sql there).